# broken packages in wine install

Tags: dependencies

i am following the exact (i hope) commands given here at this site https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu , and im at the step where i select and install one of 3 different packages: stable, dev and staging. 
    i run the command for stable, an am presented with this:[image]

i am completely new ( a few days) to linux, but i can read the info.... but no idea exactly on how to go about correcting the broken packages. i actually still dont know how to really install or uninstall anything unless its from the ubuntu software center thing.
    what exactly am i looking at and how do i go about fixing it, anyone? please and thank you :)

Comment: Did you install a ppa?

Comment: what is a ppa? i dont think i did.... i was just trying to install wine to (hopefully) run programs that i could before, when i was with windows.

Comment: If you did all the steps at the winehq page, you installed a ppa, which is a private software repository.  Unless you need the latest and greatest wine install, it's a lot simpler to just install the version of wine that is in the Ubuntu repos, and not do the ppa thing.

Comment: how do i go about doing that?

Comment: i dont even know where to get ANYTHING really...

Comment: First you need to figure out if you installed the ppa, and remove it if you did. I don't know what version of Ubuntu you are using, but if you can find the Software & Updates app, click on the Other Software tab. This will list all the ppas you have installed.  You can disable the ppa by unchecking its box.  But things can get complicated here. If you did the 'sudo apt update' step on the winehq page, you may have installed software from the ppa.  If you did, then that software has to be removed as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89416/discussion-between-dps-and-organic-marble).